# app:showAsAction="ifRoom" not working

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and am having a problem that seems to be pretty popular. None of the solutions are working for me so I can't figure out what's wrong.

I've got a Menu with 2 items in it (Search, Shop By), and I want Search to appear in the Action Bar. However, `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` is not moving Search as it still appears in the overflow.

Here is the XML for the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/shop_by"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_by"
        android:title="@string/shop_by_title"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Here is where I override onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

What am I missing?

I tried `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` and got the same behavior.

I tried `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`and got an error.

EDIT:
SOLVED!
The namespace for `app` should look like this:
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: I put my answer below

Comment: Use `always` not `ifRoom`

Comment: If you want your Search option to be always shown, use always instead of ifRoom.

Comment: Adding `orderInCategory` does not move Search out of the overflow :( However, it functions properly given that I can change the order of options in the overflow

Comment: The namespace for the `app` prefix doesn't look right. Did you do that, or did Android Studio? It should be `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`, unless something changed with the new versions.

Comment: @MikeM. for the win! Thanks for the help team.

Comment: @MikeM. That sure makes a big difference!! That's out of my radar :P. You're the champ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try adding `orderInCategory` attribute. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/shop_by"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop_by"
        android:title="@string/shop_by_title"
        android:orderInCategory="100"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:orderInCategory="99"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Use `app:showAsAction="always"` if you want to always show the menu item.

Note: the answer is updated from `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/res-auto"` to `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

kudos to @MikeM

Comment: Adding `orderInCategory` does not move Search out of the overflow :( However, it functions properly given that I can change the order of options in the overflow

Answer (score -1):

If you are using

```
android.support.v7.app.Activity
```

the xml should be like yours.

And if you are using

```
android.app.Activity
```

please use:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

instead of

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Comment: using `android:showAsAction` gives me an error that says i should use `app` and the res-auto library